# os.path.join() gives InMemoryUploadFile error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-file-upload

I have written a POST api which posts a file. I want to open the file and parse a JSON content in the file. But the line os.path.join() doesnt seem to work. I am getting "'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'" exception. Have included the code used below.

```
def schedule_load(file_name):
    print file_name
    file_json = default_storage.open(os.path.join("schedule_files", file_name), 'r')
    var = file_json.read()
    print var
    file_json.close()
    schedule = json.loads(var)
```

My POST method :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_schedule(request):
print "post_schedule"
if request.method == 'POST':
    print "if POST"
    form = ScheduleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    file_name = form['schedule_file'].value()

    if form.is_valid():
        print "is_valid"
        form.save()
        schedule_load(file_name)
        return JsonResponse({"status": "success"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"status": "Invalid file"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what you are dealing with is a `InMemoryUploadedFile` rather than a file name. Your code should change as

```
def schedule_load(file_name):
    var = file_name.read()
    print var
```